# JavaScript recursive function help to remove hyphens

Tags: javascript, recursion

I've been working on a recursion script, that dynamically creates a dropdown navigation based on a  markup.

Here's what I have so far, but I am trying to remove the hyphen before each item in the dropdown list, UNLESS it's inside a nested  as a sub-link. Does anyone have any ideas?

Here's how the recursion script is setup, with the call at the bottom.

```
var loadLinks = function runLinks(currDom, currPrependedChar) {

        var dom = currDom;
        var children = dom.children;

        for (var i = 0; i < dom.children.length; ++i) {

            var currentLink = children[i];

            switch (currentLink.nodeName) {
                case 'A':
                    var option = document.createElement('option');
                    option.innerHTML = currPrependedChar + currentLink.text;
                    option.value = currentLink.href;
                    select.appendChild(option);
                    break;
                default:
                    if (currentLink.nodeName === 'UL') {
                        currPrependedChar += currPrependedChar;
                    }
                    loadLinks(currentLink, currPrependedChar);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    loadLinks(nav, '- ');
```

Here's how it runs on JSFiddle, you can see the select nav with hyphens - http://jsfiddle.net/4jeaZ/

Comment: Wait... you *don't* want the hyphens? Then why pass a hyphen and a space to `loadLinks`?

Comment: I just want the hyphens for the sub links only. I want to pass it as loadLinks(nav); and then somehow inside re-jig it to add a hyphen for the UL a's :-)

Comment: Initially call the function with `loadLinks(nav, '');` and then the recursive call becomes `loadLinks(currentLink, currPrependedChar + "-");`

Comment: Thanks @James, that was my backup plan, it just seemed a bit of a hack and not the cleanest solution.

Comment: I think you're looking at it backwards. Find all of the links that fit your requirement, and manipulate their child element(s) that fit your requirements. No recursion necessary.

Comment: Hi @JaredFarrish, how would you suggest doing it without a recursion?

Comment: Well if you want a recursive solution where you may have many different levels nested inside you will want to append an extra hyphen for each level deep, no?  I don't think there is a more elegant solution for such a case, and if there is please educate.

Comment: [`:before {content: "--- ";}`](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/4jeaZ/1/). Older versions of some browsers don't support that. `document.querySelectorAll('#nav > li > ul > li > a')` would also work, except IE8 and lower don't support it. But you get the idea. EDIT: Of course I just realized the dropdown is part of the problem. So, still do the recursion but add the `-` after? I'm not going to mention that jQUery would probably make this really straightforward. Not gonna say it. Cross-browser DOM manipulation is the pain in the butt.

Comment: Haha, @JaredFarrish - I know jQuery would make it straightforward, but it's all fun :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just track the current level:

```
var loadLinks = function runLinks(currDom,currPrependedChar, currLevel) {
...
option.innerHTML = (currLevel++ < 1 ? '' : currPrependedChar) + currentLink.text;
...
currLevel < 2 || (currPrependedChar += currPrependedChar);
...
loadLinks(currentLink, currPrependedChar, currLevel);
...
loadLinks(nav, '- ', 0);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/4jeaZ/5/

Comment: Thanks Jared, a few options come up as 'true' 'true' though.

Comment: And if you're looking for the `-` to only append one per sub level, see: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/4jeaZ/5/

Comment: No problem. I think this one is fun: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/4jeaZ/6/ The single hyphen doesn't quite indicate the right lateral depth...

Comment: Yeah, I think the double hyphen for nested,nested would be better just one hyphen but whitespace indented.

Answer (score 0):

You could add one extra parameter to the runLinks function so that it would know the current prepended char and the sub link prepended char.

```
  var loadLinks = function runLinks(currDom, currPrependedChar, subPrependedChar) {

        var dom = currDom;
        var children = dom.children;

        for (var i = 0; i < dom.children.length; ++i) {

            var currentLink = children[i];

            switch (currentLink.nodeName) {
                case 'A':
                    var option = document.createElement('option');
                    option.innerHTML = currPrependedChar + currentLink.text;
                    option.value = currentLink.href;
                    select.appendChild(option);
                    break;
                default:
                    if (currentLink.nodeName === 'UL') {
                        currPrependedChar += subPrependedChar;
                    }
                    loadLinks(currentLink, currPrependedChar, subPrependedChar);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    loadLinks(nav, '', '- ');
```